# How to Remove border style on React AgGrid .ag-root-wrapper

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid

I can not remove border style.
The properties I want to remove are as follows.

```
border: solid 1px <<
```

And, I tried on css file.

```
.ag-root-wrapper {
    border: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

This code is **not working.**
However, if you remove the attribute through Chrome developer mode, you can remove the border.

ps. I wanted upload problem image.
But I can't. (You need at least 10 reputation to post images.)

Detail source added.

##### default.css

```
.ag-root-wrapper {
    border: none // not working
    // display: none // working!!
}
```

##### agGrid

```
import React from 'react';
import 'default.css';
import {AgGridColumn, AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

export default function Example(props) {
    return (
        <div 
            className="ag-theme-alpine" 
            style={{height: "calc(100vh - 48px)", margin: "10px",
            width: "100%"}}>
            <AgGridReact
                defaultColDef={{
                    minWidth: 100,
                    resizable: true
                }}
                colResizeDefault={'shift'}
                rowSelection={'single'}
                onGridReady={onGridReady}
                onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
                rowData={data}>
                <AgGridColumn field="cateId" width={20}/>
                <AgGridColumn field="sort" width={30}/>
                <AgGridColumn field="isUsed" width={30}/>
                <AgGridColumn field="title" width={260}/>
                <AgGridColumn field="explanation" width={500}/>
                <AgGridColumn field="gitHubUrl" width={400}/>
                <AgGridColumn field="markdownUrl" width={700}/>
            </AgGridReact>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: use `border: none;` instead of 0px...

Comment: share React code

Comment: can you put also put the minimum part of the HTML possible (the part with the same class), maybe is a typo error (I remember one day I writted *wraper* in HTML and in CSS *wrapper*) without the code I can't imagine if the same situation as happen to me before or another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you specify .ag-theme-alpine like this :

```
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-root-wrapper  {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: For anyone trying to use this within makeStyles/material, the below worked for me:
`'& .ag-root-wrapper': { border: 'none' },`